# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with strings

Tags: c

I must write a function which gets 30 names without repeated names and after that it prints random on name of this 30. But when I run the program after my second name I entered, I get Segmentation fault and I don't know why. Cause when I put the first name every thing is good.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 30  /*The size of the array of names*/
#define MAX_L 21    /*The length of a name included  the ending 0*/
#define REPEAT 10 /*The amount of getting a random name in the names list */

char names[SIZE][MAX_L];/* = { 0 } ; /*Global array for the names we get from the users*/

/*Gives back a random name in an array nameslist*/
char * get_name(){
    int random; /*the random index we get of the names list*/
    char *r; /*the string name to return*/

    random= rand()%SIZE; /*picks a random number from 0-29 */
    r= names[random]; /*r points to the random name in the list*/
    return r;
}


/*Gets from user 30 names without repeat and calls after that function get_names 10 times*/
int  main(){
    int i;  /*counter for array names list */
    int j;  /*counter for array in the first inner loop to check if there are repeated names*/
    int k;  /*counter for the repeat loop for random names*/
    int w;  /*counter for the index of the character in the string */
    bool same = true; /*says if two strings are the same or not*/

    for (i=0; i< SIZE; i++){  /*Gets from the user 30 names and initialize them in the array*/
        printf("\nPlease enter a name (repeated names forbidden until we'll get to 30 names)\n");
        scanf("%s", names[i]);

       if (i>0){
       for (j=0; j<i; j++){  /*checks if is a repeated name or not*/
        for (w=0; w< MAX_L || same ==false; w++){
            if (names[i][w] != names[j][w]){
                    if (names[i][w] >= 'a' && names[i][w] <= 'z'){ 
                            if (names[i][w] - 32 != names[j][w]) 
                                same=false;}

                else if (names[i][w] >= 'A' && names[i][w] <= 'Z'){
                            if (names[i][w] + 32 != names[j][w]) 
                                same=false;}
            }
        }   
        if (same ==true){ /*repeated name*/
             printf("\nERROR! You already entered this name!");
             return 0;}     
       }}
       printf("\nThe name you entered is: %s\n", names[i]);
    }

    for (k=0; k<REPEAT; k++){ /*Calls the function get_name 10 times to get 10 random names from the array*/
        printf("\nThe random name you got from the list is: %s", get_name());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I get Segmentation fault and I don't know why". The way to try and find out why is to run your program in a debugger.

Comment: You are returning the address of a local variable at `return r;`

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but comparing character by character is an inefficient way of comparing strings.  Something like strcmp(toupper(names[i]), toupper(names[j])) would be faster and cleaner.  Converting both names to upper case gets rid of the plus and minus 32 cases.

Comment: `w< MAX_L || same ==false` That looks pretty dangerous. The point of `w<MAX_L` is to ensure the array bounds are not exceeded. Adding `||` potentially removes that safety barrier.

Comment: And don't compare `same` to `true` or `false`. Just use `if (same)` or `if( !same )`. It is too easy to mistype the number of equal signs, creating an error that is usually very difficult to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to debug your program.

All you need to do is:

1. Compile your program with `-g` flag, e.g.: `gcc -g -Wall main.c -o prog`
2. Launch gdb: `gdb prog`
3. Set breakpoint(-s):

```sh
gdb) b 36
Breakpoint
```

4. Run your program: `(gdb) r`
5. Use `s` to step by step debug and `c` to continue to next breakpoint

And you will easily discover the cause of your segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555526f in main () at main.c:39
39                  if (names[i][w] != names[j][w]){
```

To see why exactly it segfaults you can print variables using `p %variable name%`:

```
(gdb) p i
$1 = 1
(gdb) p w
$2 = 139115
(gdb) p j
$3 = 0
(gdb) p same
$4 = false
```

So the cause is obvious: `same ==false` condition make your `w` variable overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just a question if I want make the code little bit easier with compare the string without bool and every single character in the compare section. How can I do it. I tried this code but didnt work.                                                                                                                                                          
        if (strlen(names[i]) == strlen(names[j])){
       if (strcmp(toupper(names[i]), toupper(names[j]) == 0){
              printf("\nERROR! You already entered this name!");
            return 0;
   }  }

Comment: `if (strlen(names[i]) == strlen(names[j])){
   if (strcmp(toupper(names[i]), toupper(names[j]) == 0){
          printf("\nERROR! You already entered this name!");
        return 0;
   }  
  }`

Comment: There are a lot of [warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB23x.png) for your updated code, [check out](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) `toupper` function, it's used for `int` variables, not for a string. By the way don't forget to mark my answer as accepted with ‎✓ sign.

Comment: Thanks Artem Bondar